# Troubles loading a function from python file

Tags: python

I am having trouble loading a function in a python file that i created. The entire code in the python file runs without any problems in a Jupyter Notebook. Now that i have put the code, 1:1 into a python file, i get an error "cannot import name 'get' from 'connector'" where connector is my python file, and get is the function nested inside.

I suspect that the format from Jupyter Notebook changes and into a regular python file changes the way the file is read somehow?

I wanted to move the code into a python file, as this function is usefull for mulitple projects i am doing in python when **scraping** webpages. I can call the function ratelimit function, but i can't seem to figure out what is wrong with my get command.

```
# Imports
import scraping_class
import pandas as pd
import requests,os,time


logfile="trustpilot.txt"
Connector = scraping_class.Connector(logfile)

def ratelimit(x):
    "A function that handles the rate of your calls."
    time.sleep(x) # sleep x seconds.

class Connector():
  def __init__(self,logfile,overwrite_log=False,connector_type='requests',session=False,path2selenium='',n_tries = 5,timeout=30):
    """This Class implements a method for reliable connection to the internet and monitoring. 
    It handles simple errors due to connection problems, and logs a range of information for basic quality assessments
    
    Keyword arguments:
    logfile -- path to the logfile
    overwrite_log -- bool, defining if logfile should be cleared (rarely the case). 
    connector_type -- use the 'requests' module or the 'selenium'. Will have different since the selenium webdriver does not have a similar response object when using the get method, and monitoring the behavior cannot be automated in the same way.
    session -- requests.session object. For defining custom headers and proxies.
    path2selenium -- str, sets the path to the geckodriver needed when using selenium.
    n_tries -- int, defines the number of retries the *get* method will try to avoid random connection errors.
    timeout -- int, seconds the get request will wait for the server to respond, again to avoid connection errors.
    """
    
    ## Initialization function defining parameters. 
    self.n_tries = n_tries # For avoiding triviel error e.g. connection errors, this defines how many times it will retry.
    self.timeout = timeout # Defining the maximum time to wait for a server to response.
    ## not implemented here, if you use selenium.
    if connector_type=='selenium':
      assert path2selenium!='', "You need to specify the path to you geckodriver if you want to use Selenium"
      from selenium import webdriver 
      ## HIN download the latest geckodriver here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

      assert os.path.isfile(path2selenium),'You need to insert a valid path2selenium the path to your geckodriver. You can download the latest geckodriver here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases'
      self.browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=path2selenium) # start the browser with a path to the geckodriver.

    self.connector_type = connector_type # set the connector_type
    
    if session: # set the custom session
      self.session = session
    else:
      self.session = requests.session()
    self.logfilename = logfile # set the logfile path
    ## define header for the logfile
    header = ['id','project','connector_type','t', 'delta_t', 'url', 'redirect_url','response_size', 'response_code','success','error']
    if os.path.isfile(logfile):        
      if overwrite_log==True:
        self.log = open(logfile,'w')
        self.log.write(';'.join(header))
      else:
        self.log = open(logfile,'a')
    else:
      self.log = open(logfile,'w')
      self.log.write(';'.join(header))
    ## load log 
    with open(logfile,'r') as f: # open file
        
      l = f.read().split('\n') # read and split file by newlines.
      ## set id
      if len(l)<=1:
        self.id = 0
      else:
        self.id = int(l[-1][0])+1
            
    def get(self,url,project_name):
    """Method for connector reliably to the internet, with multiple tries and simple error handling, as well as default logging function.
    Input url and the project name for the log (i.e. is it part of mapping the domain, or is it the part of the final stage in the data collection).
    
    Keyword arguments:
    url -- str, url
    project_name -- str, Name used for analyzing the log. Use case could be the 'Mapping of domain','Meta_data_collection','main data collection'. 
    """
     
    project_name = project_name.replace(';','-') # make sure the default csv seperator is not in the project_name.
    if self.connector_type=='requests': # Determine connector method.
      for _ in range(self.n_tries): # for loop defining number of retries with the requests method.
        ratelimit()
        t = time.time()
        try: # error handling 
          response = self.session.get(url,timeout = self.timeout) # make get call

          err = '' # define python error variable as empty assumming success.
          success = True # define success variable
          redirect_url = response.url # log current url, after potential redirects 
          dt = t - time.time() # define delta-time waiting for the server and downloading content.
          size = len(response.text) # define variable for size of html content of the response.
          response_code = response.status_code # log status code.
          ## log...
          call_id = self.id # get current unique identifier for the call
          self.id+=1 # increment call id
          #['id','project_name','connector_type','t', 'delta_t', 'url', 'redirect_url','response_size', 'response_code','success','error']
          row = [call_id,project_name,self.connector_type,t,dt,url,redirect_url,size,response_code,success,err] # define row to be written in the log.
          self.log.write('\n'+';'.join(map(str,row))) # write log.
          return response,call_id # return response and unique identifier.

        except Exception as e: # define error condition
          err = str(e) # python error
          response_code = '' # blank response code 
          success = False # call success = False
          size = 0 # content is empty.
          redirect_url = '' # redirect url empty 
          dt = t - time.time() # define delta t

          ## log...
          call_id = self.id # define unique identifier
          self.id+=1 # increment call_id

          row = [call_id,project_name,self.connector_type,t,dt,url,redirect_url,size,response_code,success,err] # define row
          self.log.write('\n'+';'.join(map(str,row))) # write row to log.
    else:
      t = time.time()
      ratelimit()
      self.browser.get(url) # use selenium get method
      ## log
      call_id = self.id # define unique identifier for the call. 
      self.id+=1 # increment the call_id
      err = '' # blank error message
      success = '' # success blank
      redirect_url = self.browser.current_url # redirect url.
      dt = t - time.time() # get time for get method ... NOTE: not necessarily the complete load time.
      size = len(self.browser.page_source) # get size of content ... NOTE: not necessarily correct, since selenium works in the background, and could still be loading.
      response_code = '' # empty response code.
      row = [call_id,project_name,self.connector_type,t,dt,url,redirect_url,size,response_code,success,err] # define row 
      self.log.write('\n'+';'.join(map(str,row))) # write row to log file.
    # Using selenium it will not return a response object, instead you should call the browser object of the connector.
    ## connector.browser.page_source will give you the html.
      return call_id
    

logfile="trustpilot.txt" ## name your log file.
connector = Connector(logfile)
```

I expected to be able to load my 'get' function from 'connector.py'

Comment: Please try to condense your code to a minimum example where the error occurs. This might even enable you to find the error yourself already. One such way would be to use a debugging tool and go line-by-line through the script and see where it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The following line may be the issue due to naming conflict as you Connector variable and Connector class:

```
Connector = scraping_class.Connector(logfile)
```

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work. I still get the same problem.